# How to apply self-created MDG profile to existing elements in model

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have created and successfully loaded a self created MDG profile for diagrams, elements and toolboxes. Freshly created elements show corresponding attributes but I would like to have them applied also to ones already existing in the model.

How to achieve this with EA 12?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drag you stereotype from the toolbox onto the element and choose Apply «YourStereo»

[image]

Comment: Ok, but what if there is no toolbox item defined in the MDG's toolbox? And does the above apply Stereotypes's characteristics to ALL element of same type or just the one immediatly involved? I need the "Apply to ALL" elements of same Stereo...

Comment: I found an option to synchronize all elements of a specific Stereotype by right-clicking it in the Toolbox and choose 'Synchronize Stereotype'. That is mostly what I need. Anyways, is it possible to synch all Stereos from an updated MDG model at once?

Comment: That's another question then. You can achieve this also using the API method: `Repository.CustomCommand()` see [Synchronize Steretoypes.vbs](https://github.com/GeertBellekens/Enterprise-Architect-VBScript-Library/blob/master/Framework/Tools/UML%20Profile/Synchronize%20Steretoypes.vbs) for an example that uses that feature.